# Conditions to the existence of a solution of a system of congruences

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime. Consider the following congruences:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
a_1 x & = & c_1  (\text{mod } p) \\\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\\\
a_n x & = & c_n  (\text{mod } p) \\
\end{array}
$$

Obviously, there is a solution $x$ to this system if and only if $c_1 / a_1 \equiv \ldots \equiv c_n/a_n$. I'd like to know if there is such a, sufficient and necessary, condition for more complex congruences like:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
a_1 x + b_1 y& \equiv & c_1  (\text{mod } p) \\\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\\\
a_n x + b_n y& \equiv & c_n  (\text{mod } p) \\
\end{array}
$$

I'm actually interested in the case where there are $m$ variables, but the case of $m=2$ is also of interest to me. I know I could use linear algebra to solve Ax = c, but I'd like some conditions which can be tested locally.

Comment: Carl - this question will probably get closed soon since it is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com.  However, two comments: (1) What are the conditions for such a system of equations to be soluble over the real numbers?  If you can't answer this, you should read up on linear algebra first.  (2) The integers modulo p form a field, so pretty much everything you know about linear algebra over the reals works mod p without any changes.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for local conditions as in the case of http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_to_Simultaneous_Linear_Congruences

Comment: You only have one prime -- you can't get much more local than that.

Comment: For example, is it true that there exists a solution to each pair of congruences if there exists one to the whole system?

Comment: @Carl: Watch your logical connectives! The question you just asked is totally vacuous. I think you meant "... *only if* there exists one to the whole system". Here the answer is (almost as obviously) no: consider the equations $x+y=1, x=0, y=0$ -- any two of these are simultaneously solvable but the three are obviously not simultaneously solvable. But to reiterate what others have already said, with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ these would be totally trivial undergraduate linear algebra exercises, and linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_p$ works just the same.

Answer (score 2):

See 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Everything it says works for $\mathbb{F}_p,$ since that is (luckily) a field.